How to compare row spaces of two matrices?
Let A is an m x n matrix and B is a p x n matrix and let m is not equal to p. Then how to compare row spaces of matrices A and B ? I know that if m = p , then we can easily compare the row spaces by finding the RREF of matrices A and B. That is row space of A is equal to row space of B if and only if RREF (A) = RREF (B).
However, if RREF (A) is not equal to RREF (B) then how to find out whether or not row space of A is a subset of row space of B or vice versa ?
My attempt is to find out whether or not each row vector of RREF (A) is in the span of row vectors of RREF (B) , which seems to be a lengthy process. Is there any other way to solve this problem ? I will be highly obliged for any help. Thanks in advance.

The row space of $A$ is a subset of the row space for $B$ if and only if the row space of the matrix formed by putting $A$ on top of $B$ has the same row space as $B$...

You can test the rows of $A$ one at a time using @MatthewTowers comment.

So let C is the matrix obtained by augmenting the rows of A with the rows of B. Then row space (A) is a subset of row space (B) if and only if rank (B) = rank (C). Similarly row space (B) is a subset of row space (A) if and only if rank (A) = rank (C). I have mentioned rank because it is easy to find rank from RREF of a matrix. Am I correct? Thanks for your response.

Yes, you're correct. You don't even need to get to RREF to find the rank: just row echelon form is enough.

Thank you very much @Matthew Towers for your answer.
